# Docker Swarm Distribute Build Image

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Situation:

I have a docker swarm with two agents. The docker swarm main daemon runs on my manager host (docker-machine example setup) with `--strategy random` option.

Steps:

- I build a new docker image using the docker swarm manager connection
  `docker -H tcp://$(docker-machine ip manager):3376 build -t test123 .`
- I startup multiple containers using the manager connection

  `docker -H tcp://$(docker-machine ip manager):3376 run -d test123 sleep 20
  docker -H tcp://$(docker-machine ip manager):3376 run -d test123 sleep 20
  docker -H tcp://$(docker-machine ip manager):3376 run -d test123 sleep 20
  docker -H tcp://$(docker-machine ip manager):3376 run -d test123 sleep 20`

The docker container is always executed on the host which was also used for building the image.

Is there a way to automatically distribute the build image to other hosts?

I know that i could use a docker registry and just push and pull the image but i want to avoid this.

Another solution i found was to save the image to a tgz and import it. A import on a docker-swarm host (manager) automatically distributes the image to all agents. (at least this was what i observed)

Is there maybe another option?

Comment: Is there a reason for trying to avoid a registry? Doing save/load and similar sounds like a lot more work than setting up a registry

Comment: My current solution uses the registry approach but that has some drawbacks:
1. Registry cleanup is not fully supported (afaik) GC must be invoked manually
2.Testing Docker Swarm using an insecure registry is also not easy. I had a lot of issues with this.
3. My image is only used half an hour. Deploying it seems overkill

Comment: Happy to hear the drawbacks, and if something can be done to improve those. I'd hate to see users having to jump through hoops to achieve something that should be trivial

Comment: 1. A docker registry from which images could be easily removed would be great. This is the main reason why i want to avoid the registry for now. My application may generate a log of images which i can't purge at the moment. I even thought about starting a throw-away registry but handling dynamic insecure registries is not easy with docker. 2. Having an option to trust any insecure registry on a docker swarm would also be helpful for testing purposes.

Comment: I think this is on the roadmap for version 2.4, see https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/462. A dirty workaround could be to use a volume for storage, and to flush all images, stop the registry, delete the volume, and start the registry again. Agreed; dirty workaround, but may do the trick.